# Unmarshalling XML generic tag into type based on attribute

Tags: xml, go

I have an XML document (a Confluence Wiki space export), and it's entirely composed of tags representing generic objects. The type of that generic object is only denoted by a "class" attribute of that tag, and then the properties are denoted by generic property tags, again with their names denoted by a "name" attribute.

Here's an example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-generic datetime="2020-02-21 18:45:18">
  <object class="User2ContentRelationEntity" package="com.atlassian.confluence.internal.relations.dao">
    <id name="id">109970422</id>
    <property name="targetContent" class="Page" package="com.atlassian.confluence.pages"><id name="id">109708423</id>
    </property>
    <property name="sourceContent" class="ConfluenceUserImpl" package="com.atlassian.confluence.user"><id name="key"><![CDATA[00a8230c48efa7b90148efaa6715070a]]></id>
    </property>
    <property name="targetType" enum-class="RelatableEntityTypeEnum" package="com.atlassian.confluence.internal.relations">PAGE</property>
    <property name="relationName"><![CDATA[collaborator]]></property>
    <property name="creationDate">2018-12-28 16:04:59.000</property>
    <property name="lastModificationDate">2018-12-28 16:04:59.000</property>
    <property name="creator" class="ConfluenceUserImpl" package="com.atlassian.confluence.user"><id name="key"><![CDATA[00a8230c48efa715070a]]></id>
    </property>
    <property name="lastModifier" class="ConfluenceUserImpl" package="com.atlassian.confluence.user"><id name="key"><![CDATA[00a8230c48efaa6715070a]]></id>
    </property>
  </object>
</hibernate-generic>
```

I can unmarshal these all into a similarly generic struct, but that's really not a helpful way to work with the data.

I've even written some code that lets me output new Go code with structs representing each of the object types and their properties, but if I want to populate those from the XML, it looks like I'd have to start by unmarshalling into the generic object and then also produce a bunch of code that then maps from the generic representation to the specific, for each property of each type of object.

Is there a better way to unmarshal this XML that would avoid having to do this?

**Edit**: To clarify: the property names seem to reflect properties of an underlying Java object, so while there are a few types of object class ("Page", "BodyContent", "Attachment", etc), and each has their own set of property names, the names are the same for each instance of that object, and don't change.

Comment: Your question needs more use-case details. Is there a finite number of `name`s? Then a single struct could be fashion. If the `name`s could include new ones in the future, then you're stuck with using a `map`. Can you provide more context?

Comment: @colminator: Added some clarification, hopefully?